# Can uplodading a file using org.apache.net.ftp wait infinitely?

Tags: apache

I am using apache.net.ftp api to download from and upload to ftp server. Its working fine in normal scenarios.
But the issue starts when there is some latency or connection is closed by the server for some reasons.
Here comes the time-out. I found a parameter 'SO_TIMEOUT' which is considered when reading from socket. So, I used ftpClient.setSoTimeout(time in millis) method to set it which will be used while downloading a file. It worked fine.

I am not getting how to set time-out while uploading the file to the ftp-server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I asking a wrong question or right question in a wrong way? There are no replies to it..

Answer (score 0):

Check the following things to make sure everything is running fine,and then try again::
 Check the Firewall setting,if any which might be blocking the incoming connections and the connection timeout.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your reply.
For now I don't want to get into the reasons why connectivity is lost. Yes, it is important but right now I want to make my code able to come out of any situation. I just want to know whether my program will wait infinitely or not when uploading a file. And if yes how can I avoid it